# How to get data to ejs file?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using global array named 'users' to store name, password and city of a user. When a new user registers, it takes name and password of the user and push it into array 'users'. After successful registration user is redirected to details page where again the user enters the city and submits the form. Again the user is redirected to the new page where the name and city of the user is to be shown. I am getting the name of the user but city is undefined.

Here is my server.js code:

```
    var users = []
  app.get('/',checkAuthenticated, (req, res)=>{
   res.render("index.ejs", 
   { name: req.user.name,
    city: req.user.city
   });
    console.log(users);
  })
  app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res)=>{
  try{
   const hashedPassword =await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
   users.push({
       name:req.body.name,
       password:hashedPassword
   })
   res.redirect('/details')
   } catch{
   res.redirect('/register')
  }
 })

 app.post('/details',checkAuthenticated, (req, res)=>{
 try{
    users.push({
        city: req.body.city,
      })
    res.redirect('/')
  } catch{
    res.redirect('/details')
  }
 })
```

Here is my index.ejs code:

```
 <h1>Hi <%= name %></h1>
 <h1>city: <%= city%></h1>
```

In my console output I am getting 'users' as:

```
  [ { 
name: 'lilly',
password:
 '$2b$10$NejINmFcHYLWaxe1xqb.BuojaWyVFQWeNC.FCHskrTMelNow1TS3G' },
{ city: 'xyz'} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In node.js, `Class` is seen as the default object for any actual *class* in your program. So when the node tokenizer (the thing that helps your code be seen as machine code) comes through and looks at that `Class` with an uppercase c, it thinks of it as you extremely weirdly trying to define a class. I recommend renaming that variable to something that won't conflict as much. Even just making the name lowercase might fix your problem.

Comment: I have added console output for more information and also changed 'Class' to 'city' still facing the same problem. @Shronk

Comment: in users, it looks like city is a completely seperate member in  the array, is there a reason for that?